# How many bytes in a Scala Char?

Tags: scala

So, today I learned I can fit at least three bytes in a Scala `Char`.

```
scala> "䕖".charAt(0)
val res4: Char = 䕖
```

How is this possible, where is this documented?

Comment: +1 For that last question as it hits really hard. It basically embodies my entire pain when working with scala.

Comment: Why did you come to the conclusion that you can fit at least 3 bytes in a `Char`? (Did you have a specific encoding in mind, such as UTF-8?). In Java and the JVM (on which Scala runs) a `char` is 16 bits (2 bytes) and contains an UTF-16 character. Note that a character that is 16 bits in UTF-16 may be more than 16 bits when encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: that might be the answer, I'll check if I can put that in utf16, I used a character I thought was not in utf16

Answer (score 4):

The Scala Language Specification does not specify any particular size for the [numeric subrange value types](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#numeric-value-types). It only specifies the existence of certain implicit conversions, as well as certain methods.

In particular, the SLS specifies the following relationship of implicit conversions:

> ```
> Byte - Short
>              \
>                Int - Long - Float - Double
>              /
>         Char
> ```

This *implies* but does not specify that the range of `scala.Char` is **NOT-GREATER-THAN** the range of `scala.Int`. However, that is *all* that is guaranteed about the range of `scala.Char`.

The [Scala Standard Library documentation](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/) has the following to say about [`scala.Char`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Char.html):

> `Char`, a 16-bit unsigned integer (equivalent to Java's `char` primitive type) is a subtype of `scala.AnyVal`. Instances of `Char` are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system.
>
> There is an implicit conversion from `scala.Char` => `scala.runtime.RichChar`
> which provides useful non-primitive operations.

It is, however, not clear to me whether this documentation is meant as a *specification* that *all* implementations of Scala *must* comply with, or a *description* of what *this particular implementation* of Scala does.

So, according to the Scala Language Specification, the size of a `scala.Char` can be pretty much anything. According to the Scala Standard Library Documentation, the size of a `scala.Char` is 16 bits, however it is not clear whether that is guaranteed for all Scala implementations, or if it only applies to Scala-JVM.